# decode curl response gzip multipart attachment in PHP

Tags: c#, php, curl, soap, gzip

I am trying to decode a binary zipped attachment received from a curl request, the attachment is an xml file but sent as binary by the API end point. Here is the full request I received:

```
--_=4883624417507473IBM4883624417507473MOKO
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: 30854c92-252a-4cb0-ae65-18ecf0de28d5
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><ns2:Messaging xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ebxml-msg/ebms/v3.0/ns/core/200704/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true" wsu:Id="soapheader-1">
<rest of xml elements have been removed!>
</soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="soapbody"></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--_=4883624417507473IBM4883624417507473MOKO
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Part1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <Attachment1>
Content-Type: application/gzip

‹íWÝOÛ0Ÿ´ÿáÔ—¾9-* ªP‰Ñn«¥*Ý´    ¡É8Wj-±#Ûé‡Ðþ÷ÙI!n  LŒ!ÄÛ}ùî|?ß%öf(,’XèýÚÔ˜´úB‘K9#4˜LD€Î†4¶HD
­uÂcºàI–œZ¹âfIe„žRR…A¥.Ì£ô
&Ú£-éÎ&§ŸFäKo@úƒÏ'¤ž*\wÖ©j¸a°çt*•!]ÔLñÔYtÆŠ
p­-ß„ÎC­'YlÏÞ2$Ëë’,)ÒÚPÁô#{>á¨:6Õ{õ¥Ú#­ûÀ/Ã¿+²õ„‘†Æ ²äÈ W!Êò¼€0S,d×Uã®
ó?•ERE4¨´G{¤_ŽÂOT*½#c\WÛ
‰'ðiýŠ‘k=rƒjÌRª5F@3cOp{6EöûºGA·ýìÐM(_t·ÝÎKu›R!0†yTà÷ŽÜcÛ}©¦{MÈ½‰qÙl<t™ÀEŠÌXÄÐ9×ïýu7Jÿ£]0p„LªèWcžp›t%Ëg×Ý¯íì6öZÛ­Övs¯v£Økì×†?{ßãR<^¦¹xÔsÒÆÔ¢â;«ÐÝö–Š¶yÀbáÎÞ·\Ü©/£®î¾Æ¯ØòiÈÁø$º?ŽÍÂµÿxgÁ+þ³ítbw
z‰ñ„4ùGlDoèÆH5“ÂØK™)ÐrbæT!¤JÎxdßÛ*òíçîÄ]4ùP»•ÆèÀú
ÌºûÃ^R†P_3ŸÏ‰52HégÂÔaJÝZ'lg&£Ò©JîÀ×Æuv*í~qß$©áºÓÛPý—ë¯\˜6Ìm–yåÜªÇÅ¥-»rù^ç}¶*ÆùÆ}ÎTzs{ÝræU¯,o^x¯}v«lg¯ñŠ ÷7ÿšÅši1€‚ü¨J7\”ëŠ
V¯x‚lvR)è|üðo?M/
--_=4883624417507473IBM4883624417507473MOKO--
```

I have been searching and trying different things but couldn't decode the attachment, I used the following to get the attachment part only:

```
preg_match('/(?<xml><.*?\?xml version=.*>)/', $response, $match);
$xml = $match['xml'];
$offset = strpos($response, $xml) + strlen($xml . PHP_EOL);
$attach = substr($response, $offset);
```

I have a working C#.net code connecting to the same API as below:

```
byte[] myData;
byte[] rv;
using (var webResponse = req.GetResponse())
{
   var responseHeaderstream = webResponse.Headers.ToByteArray();
   var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
   myData = ReadFully(responseStream);
   responseStream.Dispose();
   rv = new byte[responseHeaderstream.Length + myData.Length];
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(responseHeaderstream, 0, rv, 0, responseHeaderstream.Length);
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(myData, 0, rv, responseHeaderstream.Length, myData.Length);                    
}
```

and then using the following code to loop and read any attachment(s) found then unzip any found attachments and the result is an XML file, this type of request should only have a single attachment:

```
Dim memstream As Stream = New MemoryStream(rv)
Dim entity As MimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(memstream)
Dim attachments = New List(Of MimePart)()
Dim multiparts = New List(Of Multipart)()
Dim iter = New MimeIterator(entity)
While iter.MoveNext()
   Dim multipart = TryCast(iter.Parent, Multipart)
   Dim part = TryCast(iter.Current, MimePart)
   If multipart IsNot Nothing AndAlso part IsNot Nothing AndAlso part.IsAttachment Then
       multiparts.Add(multipart)
       attachments.Add(part)
   End If
End While

For i As Integer = 0 To attachments.Count - 1
    multiparts(i).Remove(attachments(i))
Next

For Each attachment In attachments
   Using memory = New MemoryStream()
       attachment.Content.DecodeTo(memory)
       Dim bytes = memory.ToArray()
       If attachment.ContentType.MimeType = "application/gzip" Then
          strAtchmnt = Unzip(bytes)
       Else
          strAtchmnt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
       End If
   End Using
Next
```

and here are the other functions needed to decode the attachment:

```
Public Shared Function Unzip(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As String
    Using msi = New MemoryStream(bytes)
        Using mso = New MemoryStream()
            Using gs = New GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                CopyTo(gs, mso)
            End Using
            Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
Public Shared Sub CopyTo(ByVal src As Stream, ByVal dest As Stream)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
    Dim cnt As Integer
    cnt = -1
    While cnt <> 0
        cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        If cnt <> 0 Then dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt)
    End While
End Sub
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Here is the full curl request, the $pulreq is a signed xml document which there is no need to include here:

```
$guid = $this->guidv4();
$guidstring = "<" . $guid . "@ATODN-".substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 9).">";
$boundary = "_=Part_".dechex(time()).".". time();
$content_type_header = 'Content-Type: multipart/related; '
            .'type="application/xml"; '
            .'boundary="' . $boundary . '"; '
            .'start="'.$guidstring.'"; '
            .'start-info="application/soap+xml";';
$accept_header = 'Accept: multipart/related';
$transfer_encoding_header = 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
$headers = array($content_type_header, $accept_header, $transfer_encoding_header);
$postData  = "--" . $boundary . "\r\n"
            ."Content-Type: application/soap+xml\r\n"
            ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
            ."Content-ID: ".$guidstring."\r\n\r\n"
            .$pulreq . "\r\n"
            ."--" .$boundary . "\r\n";
$curl = curl_init('https://xxxx/services/xxxx-async-pull');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    throw new Exception('cURL error:<br>' . curl_error($curl));
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: Are you making a curl request with php? If yes, can you share those codes.

Comment: Yes, it is a php curl request and I have included the full curl request.

Comment: So you are posting an xml and then also receiving an xml as a response from the same request. And your question is how to decode this received xml file. Is that correct?

Comment: It is a multipart soap response and I need to decode the binary (gzip) attachment part. the decoding should generate an xml file which is the one I am after as it has the request status messages.

Comment: Please clarify the response is independent of the file `$pulreq` that you are posting and we are not calling a `request` as a `response`

Comment: Also curl does the conversions for you automatically. Simply set the request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` and the response will be automatically unzipped and inflated.

Comment: The original soap request has no connection to the decoding process. I am just trying to decode the attachment part and after a successful decoding, I should be able to get an XML string. The sample provided in the question is a valid response which if successfully decoded, it should generate the correct xml string.

Comment: I have tried that before but unfortunately it does not make any difference, I keep getting the same exact response "binary/gzip attachment" regardless of the request encoding type. After so many tries, I don't think I will receive a decoded response via curl, that's why I need to find away decoding the attachment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the solution is really simple but didn't think about it before
Once I extracted the decoded attachment, all I needed is:

```
$xml_string = gzdecode($decoded_attachment);
```

and the result is the expected XML attachment

Answer (score 1):

if we assume that the first part of the data until the first instance of \r\n is the "section separator", and we assume for each section the metadata is separated by \r\n, and that for each section, the metadata and actual data is separated by "\r\n\r\n" (this seems to be the case, and is very reminiscent of how the `multipart/form-data`-format looks!), then extracting the sections would be something like

```php
function sectionExtractor(string $raw):array{
    $rn="\r\n";
    $separatorEndPos=strpos($raw,$rn);
    $separator=substr($raw,0, $separatorEndPos);
    // remove separator
    $raw = substr($raw, $separatorEndPos+strlen($rn));
    $rawSections = explode($rn.$separator,$raw);
    $parsedSections = array();
    foreach($rawSections as $rawSection){
        $metadataDataSeparator=$rn.$rn;
        $metadataDataSeparatorPosition = strpos($rawSection, $metadataDataSeparator);
        $metadata=substr($rawSection, 0, $metadataDataSeparatorPosition);
        $metadata = explode($rn, $metadata);
        $metadata = array_filter($metadata, 'strlen'); // probably a bug in separator exploding logic..
        $data = substr($rawSection, $metadataDataSeparatorPosition + strlen($metadataDataSeparator));
        $parsedSections[]=["metadata"=>$metadata, "data"=>$data];
    }
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.3.0', '>=')) {
        unset($parsedSections[array_key_last($parsedSections)]);//a bug in exploding the last separator..
    }
    return $parsedSections;
}
$sections = sectionExtractor($data);
var_export($sections);
```

which on your data yields

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'metadata' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit',
      1 => 'Content-ID: 30854c92-252a-4cb0-ae65-18ecf0de28d5',
      2 => 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8',
    ),
    'data' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><ns2:Messaging xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ebxml-msg/ebms/v3.0/ns/core/200704/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true" wsu:Id="soapheader-1">
<rest of xml elements have been removed!>
</soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="soapbody"></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'metadata' => 
    array (
      1 => 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Part1',
      2 => 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary',
      3 => 'Content-ID: <Attachment1>',
      4 => 'Content-Type: application/gzip',
    ),
    'data' => '‹íWÝOÛ0Ÿ´ÿáÔ—¾9-* ªP‰Ñn«¥*Ý´    ¡É8Wj-±#Ûé‡Ðþ÷ÙI!n  LŒ!ÄÛ}ùî|?ß%öf(,’XèýÚÔ˜´úB‘K9#4˜LD€Î†4¶HD
­uÂcºàI–œZ¹âfIe„žRR…A¥.Ì£ô
&Ú£-éÎ&§ŸFäKo@úƒÏ\'¤ž*\\wÖ©j¸a°çt*•!]ÔLñÔYtÆŠ
p­-ß„ÎC­\'YlÏÞ2$Ëë’,)ÒÚPÁô#{>á¨:6Õ{õ¥Ú#­ûÀ/Ã¿+²õ„‘†Æ ²äÈ W!Êò¼€0S,d×Uã®
ó?•ERE4¨´G{¤_ŽÂOT*½#c\\WÛ
‰\'ðiýŠ‘k=rƒjÌRª5F@3cOp{6EöûºGA·ýìÐM(_t·ÝÎKu›R!0†yTà÷ŽÜcÛ}©¦{MÈ½‰qÙl<t™ÀEŠÌXÄÐ9×ïýu7Jÿ£]0p„LªèWcžp›t%Ëg×Ý¯íì6öZÛ­Övs¯v£Økì×†?{ßãR<^¦¹xÔsÒÆÔ¢â;«ÐÝö–Š¶yÀbáÎÞ·\\Ü©/£®î¾Æ¯ØòiÈÁø$º?ŽÍÂµÿxgÁ+þ³ítbw
z‰ñ„4ùGlDoèÆH5“ÂØK™)ÐrbæT!¤JÎxdßÛ*òíçîÄ]4ùP»•ÆèÀú
ÌºûÃ^R†P_3ŸÏ‰52HégÂÔaJÝZ\'lg&£Ò©JîÀ×Æuv*í~qß$©áºÓÛPý—ë¯\\˜6Ìm–yåÜªÇÅ¥-»rù^ç}¶*ÆùÆ}ÎTzs{ÝræU¯,o^x¯}v«lg¯ñŠ ÷7ÿšÅši1€‚ü¨J7\\”ëŠ
V¯x‚lvR)è|üðo?M/',
  ),
)
```

from there the raw zip data is in
$sections[1]["data"] , once you have that you can use something like [PECL zipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) like

```
$zipRaw = $sections[1]["data"];
$tmpZipFileHandle = tmpfile();
$tmpZipFileLocation = stream_get_meta_data($tmpZipFileHandle)['uri'];
fwrite($tmpZipFileHandle, $zipRaw);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($tmpZipFileLocation);
$zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
```

then the contents of the zipfile should be extracted to `/my/destination/dir/`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this issue. I am on PHP 7.2 and the array_key_last is not available, but I already extracted the response into an array which has the zip contents only. When I try the second section of your code, I get "ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object", so I tried to unzip a sample file using the same folder and was successfully extracted. And it seems that the issue is with this line "$zip->open($tmpZipFileLocation);" as when I try "$x = $zip->open($tmpZipFileLocation);" it returns false which means the file wasn't successfully opened!

Comment: @Alan probably a bug in the zip binary extraction code. perhaps off by 1 or 2 bytes. save the bytes your code extracts to a file (like `file_put_contents("test.zip",$bytesYouExtracted");`), then open the file in [a hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HxD), does the bytes you extracted start with the hex `50 4B 03 04` ? what bytes does it start with?

Comment: @Alan also compare the binary extracted by your own code with the binary extracted by my `function sectionExtractor` above, do they extract exactly the same binary data?

Comment: I assume that $bytesYouExtracted means the $sections[1]["data"] which is the zipped contents, then no I got byte 0 starts with 1f e2 80 b9, and got the same when using your code, but I had to disable the line "unset($parsedSections[array_key_last($parsedSections)]);" due to the PHP 7.2 version. I am getting (0,1,2) indexes, index 1 holding the zipped contents and 2 is empty? not sure if you got the same? Also, were you able to decode the zipped attachment into an xml file?

Comment: @Alan `I assume that $bytesYouExtracted means the $sections[1]["data"] ` - correct. `I got byte 0 starts with 1f e2 80 b9` - hmm, that does not look like a zip file at all, all zip files are supposed to start with 50 4B.. `not sure if you got the same?` - yup. also it's impossible to attempt decoding of the sample data you provided as a text post on stackoverflow. when you copy-pasted the binary data into your web browser, your browser did its best to try to convert the zip binary to unicode, but the data is corrupted, for example, null-bytes are lost, carriage-return-bytes are lost, etc.

Comment: I have replaced the array_key_last in your function with ** end($parsedSections);  $key = key($parsedSections);  unset($parsedSections[$key]); ** and I got the same array structure that you have posted, but still has the same hex 1f e2 80 b9, and still the same error "ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object", my dev pc has zip version 1.15.4 and Libzip version 1.4.0, not sure if it is to do with the current zip extension on my pc?

Comment: `1f e2` is not zip =/ can you post the entire response as base64 somewhere? https://pastebin.com/ or something, like `echo base64_encode($response);die();` , then i can have a closer look at it

Comment: I am a bit confused, as file_put_content won't save as a zip file even if we change the extension? and thus the hex is wrong. so I did some testing now and saved a text file then used it to create new zip file "ZipArchive()", and the hex is correct 50 4b 03 04. I think the fwrite line does not write anything to the temp file? I assume the tmpfile is holding some kind of stream by reading the zip contents and then using the ZipArchive() to extract the actual contents?